# How to load data into redshift table using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, load

Hi I have file in which columns are separated by '|' and rows are separated by ','. I want to load into table using the copy command. Could you suggest me how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Amazon Redshift [COPY Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) has a `DELIMITER` parameter that "specifies the single ASCII character that is used to separate fields in the input file, such as a pipe character ( | ), a comma ( , ), or a tab ( \t )."

However, all rows **must** end with a newline (CR). It is **not possible** to specify that rows end with a comma.

You would need to **pre-process this file** to convert it into a format compatible with the Amazon Redshift COPY command.

Alternatively, since you mention Python, you could write a Python program to read the rows and then send the data to Redshift using `INSERT` statements. However, this is much less efficient that using a `COPY` command and also requires that you establish a connection to Redshift via an SQL client (eg `psycopg2`) or the [Amazon Redshift Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html).